# php and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Ok i have tried this quite a few times now.  I still cannot figure it out.

Thisis my problem.  I want to take any 
    `<br><br>` and turn it into `<br>`

So this is what i do

    `$test = ereg_match("/<br><br>/", "<br>", "<br><br>Test<br><br>");
    echo $test;`

It produces `$test == "Test"` rather than `$test = "<br>Test<br>"`

Any help?  Then i would like to expand it so that any `<br\s*\/{0, 1}>\s*<br\s*\/{0, 1}>` So that any two seperated by space can be turned into 1.  Any help?

Comment: You probably wanted to use `preg_replace` rather than `ereg_match`.

Comment: Look below :) I tried that too.  So i tried ereg, eregi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use str_replace

```
<?php

$str = "<br><br>Test<br><br>";

echo str_replace("<br><br>", "<br>", $str);
```

**Update**

Example:

http://codepad.org/MWzg81Qy

To replace 2 or more br's(with unlimited spacing)... you can do preg_replace:

```
<?php

$str = "<br><br     >    <br><br>Test<br     ><br>";

echo preg_replace("/(\s*<br\s*>)+/", "<br>", $str);
```

http://codepad.org/CrltyhSs

Comment: What about expanding it so that any two BR's that have some set of space `<br\s*>\s*<br\s*>`

Comment: +1. In terms of both performance and maintenance, string manipulation is usually better than regex when both are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you're after but using [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) will be considerably more efficient than a regular expression.

i.e.: `$test = str_replace('<br><br>', '<br>', $sourceString);`

Incidentally, I'd be tempted to replace the `<br>` tags with `<br />` in this day and age as well. :-)

Comment: basically, the point is that i allow users to enter in input, and i do not want them to do something like `hey i am super annoying!!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>s<br><br><br><br>ee<br><br><br>me<br><br><br><br>go!!!<br><br><br><br>`

Comment: @Michael What you're attempting is a very poor means of handling this - you should simply output what the user entered (i.e.: output the entity encoded '<' and '>' equivalents) unless you're specifically allowing them to enter HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly have a typo in your function names. The **p**reg_* functions have mostly replaced the old **e**reg_ functions.

Your second regex should be written as:

```
print preg_replace("#<br\s*/?>\s*<br\s*/?>#", "<br>", "<br><br>Test");
```

The `?` is shorthand for your `{0,1}`, and by using `#` as delimiter you spare the extraneous escaping of forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
preg_replace("#<br[^>]*><br[^>]*>#", "<br>", "<br><br>Test<br><br>");

Both these lines produce same output:
var_dump(preg_replace("#<br[^>]*><br[^>]*>#", "<br>", "<br><br>Test<br><br>"));
var_dump(preg_replace("#<br[^>]*><br[^>]*>#", "<br>", "<br /><br>Test<br><br>"));

OUTOUT: string(12) "<br>Test<br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 2 BR separated by optional whitespace:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>(?:\s*<br[^>]*>){1}/', '<br>', $str);
```

2 or more BR separated by optional whitespace:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>(?:\s*<br[^>]*>){1,}/', '<br>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Lewis says, use string manipulation if you don't need to account for variation in the input string. On the other hand, if you want to collapse any multiple `<br>` or `<br/>` tags into a single tag, allowing for whitespace inside them, this should work for you:

```
$result = preg_replace('#(<\s*br\s*(/\s*)?>){2,}#', '<br>', $subject);
```

I'm not totally sure why your version isn't working, but if the above doesn't work, there's probably something else going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  I am so stupid.

In a seperate file i had

`define("ALLOWED_TAGS", "");
    ...
    ...
    ...
    define("ALLOWED_TAGS", "my tags blah blah blah");`

Sorry for wasting everyones time.  GG

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace where you can.  Given your comments on stuff such as wanting to replace `<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>` with just 1 `<br>`, do this:

```
while(strpos($inputstring,'<br><br>'))  //while <br><br> can be found in string
{
    $inputstring = str_replace('<br><br>', '<br>', $inputstring);  //replace <br><br>
}
```

PHP has a bad implementation of regular expressions, and they take a much much longer time to do in PHP than it's string manipulations.  Like a whole greater order of magnitude time longer.

To catch various different potential issues with the tags, you can do:

```
$searchArray = array('<br><br>','<br /><br />','other potential spellings');
while(stripos($inputstring,$searchArray))  //while case insensitive search strings are in string
{
    $inputstring = str_ireplace($searchArray, '<br />', $inputstring);  //replace case insensitive strings
}
```

You can also use `strip_tags` just to remove any unwanted tags all together:

```
$inputstring = strip_tags($inputstring, '<p><a><b><i><other allowed tags>');
```

But, of course, this would remove all `<br>` tags.

Comment: PHP has a bad implementation of regular expressions?  That's news to me.  Are you perhaps talking about the (deprecated) `ereg` functions?  Because the `preg` functions (which are powered by the PCRE regex library) work just fine.  I doubt performance is a legitimate concern anyway, especially given that the regex is being applied to user input.